Tornado timeout for read_bytes
I would like to wait only 5 seconds for a response; if it does not arrive, just move forward.
async def Test(self, _connection):
    _connection.write('heartbeat\n'.encode('utf-8'))
    try:
        length = await asyncio.wait_for(_connection.read_bytes(4), timeout=5)
        return length
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("The read operation timed out.")
    except Exception:
        pass

This code works but in case I try to read data again, the following message is printed:
Already reading

I took a look into tornado code and it looks like they do not handle properly the asyncio.CancelledError fot this case (not sure if this is possible).
